# Is this a valid 2D Array definition in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I just saw something like this in a C++ code (that compiles and probably works in VS2010):

```
int *p = new int[8, 6];
p[2, 3] = 5;
```

Is this a new notation for creating multidimensional arrays in C++? Or am I missing something? As far as I remember, arrays are declared this way [a][b] not [a, b] in C++. It would be highly appreciated if you could explain this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is valid syntax, but it doesn't specify 2D arrays.  It's using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), so it's equivalent to:

```
int *p = new int[6];
p[3] = 5;
```